# QML mouse absolute position in MouseArea

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

How to get the absolute mouse position from the mouse area ?
I need to have it to show a popup a the correct position

```
Item {
    Menu {
        id: menu
        MenuItem {
            onTriggered: {
               // Need Mouse absolute position
            }
        }
    }
    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            menu.popup()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably found the answer already, but I'll put my solution here for others looking for the same thing.

The below function will find the absolute position of the mouse area.
And then you can add mouseX and mouseY accordingly to get mouse position.

```
Item {
  Menu {
    id: menu
    MenuItem {
      onTriggered: {
        var absolutePos = getAbsolutePosition(source);
        // Need Mouse absolute position
      }
    }
  }
  MouseArea {
    id: mouseArea
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
      menu.popup()
    }
  }
  function getAbsolutePosition(node) {
      var returnPos = {};
      returnPos.x = 0;
      returnPos.y = 0;
      if(node !== undefined && node !== null) {
          var parentValue = getAbsolutePosition(node.parent);
          returnPos.x = parentValue.x + node.x;
          returnPos.y = parentValue.y + node.y;
      }
      return returnPos;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a simple solution when you have only 1 level, but mapToItem is preferred as more flexible and easier to maintain, as explained is the answer of indalive and mine below https://stackoverflow.com/a/44779025/4223664

Answer (score 9):

#### Short answer

- Map to/from another Item: [`mapToItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapToItem-method), [`mapFromItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapFromItem-method-1)
- Map to/from global (from Qt 5.7): [`mapToGlobal`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapToGlobal-method), [`mapFromGlobal`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapToGlobal-method)

```
    onClicked: {
        var positionInPopup = mapToItem(popup, mouse.x, mouse.y)
    }
```

#### Longer answer

Like hinted by indalive, the preferred method for mapping coordinates is by using [`mapToItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapToItem-method), available for any Item. It transforms coordinates (and size) from current Item coordinates system (if not specified otherwise) to another Item coordinates system. And the [`mapFromItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapFromItem-method-1) counterpart does the reverse, naturally.

From Qt 5.7, you also have [`mapToGlobal`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapToGlobal-method), which will give you coordinates in the system/screen referential.

```
MouseArea {

    // ...

    onPositionChanged: {
        var positionInRoot = mapToItem(root, mouse.x, mouse.y)
        var positionInWindow = mapToItem(window.contentItem, mouse.x, mouse.y)
        var globalPosition = mapToGlobal(mouse.x, mouse.y)

        console.log("For root: " + positionInRoot )
        console.log("For window: " + positionInWindow)
        console.log("For system: " + globalPosition)
    }
}
```

Given the example above, and ...

- your `MouseArea` is close to `root`, a bit further from your `Window` top left corner
- the Window itself is 1000px+ from the leftmost of your screen(s)

... you will see:

> For root: QPointF(10, 0)
>
> For window: QPointF(150, 100)
>
> For system: QPointF(1230, 120)

#### Caveat with `Window` type

When converting to/from a `Window` (QML type), you need to use its `contentItem` property, as mapTo/From only work with `Item`s.

Answer (score 4):

In this case mouseArea fills his parent (anchors.fill: parent), therefore mouseArea.mouseX and mouseArea.mouseY are absolute mouse position. For relative positions you should use mapFromItem and mapToItem functions http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapToItem-method

Comment: Great! new link is [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapFromItem-method-1)

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation for the onClicked signal in Mouse Area(http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-mousearea.html#onClicked-signal) you are given a MouseEvent param named mouse. Using the MouseEvent object(http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-mouseevent.html) you can access the mouse positions inside the onClick handler with

```
mouse.x
mouse.y
```

Comment: Thx, but it is not absolute coordinates.

Comment: It is relative within the container of the mouse area.  Since you should never be positioning elements absolutely anyway I fail to see how it would be helpful.

Comment: @Deadron Pop up a Window where the mouse was clicked